# How to set a flag for cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, azure-active-directory, cert-manager

I am following [that guide](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/azuredns/#managed-identity-using-aad-pod-identities). At the end of the section there is a sentence:

> To enable this authentication mechanism for Issuers, you will need to set `--issuer-ambient-credentials` flag on cert-manager controller to true.

I am looking all over the documentation, the internet and cannot find out how do I set any flag for the cert manager? There is a [guide about cert-manager-controller](https://cert-manager.io/v0.16-docs/cli/controller/) but it doesn't say a word if I should install the controller or how to access that. There is no such option in help command of `kubectl cert-manager`. I was trying to add flag in my Certificate in yaml file, but don't know where exactly it could be. I was also trying to edit cert-manager pod, but anywhere I put the following:

```
extraArgs:
- --issuer-ambient-credentials=true
```

It cannot accept it:

> Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": ValidationError(Pod.metadata): unknown field "extraArgs" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta

I deleted cert-manager and now trying to install it this way:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.7.2/cert-manager.yaml --edit
```

But still have problem determining where to put the flag.

I am using cert-manager v1.7.2, if that does matter. Downloaded tar.gz from github.
kubectl v 1.22.0

I am afraid the resolution is very simple but I don't see it...

Comment: Please share your full manifest. Anyway setting arg as you did `- --issuer-ambient-credentials=true` is incorrect, it should be consists of `key: value` pair.

Comment: What manifest? I downloaded cert-manager from github, it was ready executable.

Answer (score 1):

The only way was to reinstall cert-manager. This time I used yaml file from their github and for deployment of cert-manager I added:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        args:
          - --issuer-ambient-credentials=true
```